# Isolate value of string by number of characters

Tags: javascript, jquery

How I can isolate value of string (00010111001101000001011100011001) on strings by number of characters(8) use jquery and javascript?

I want this:
Result: [
"00010111",
"00110100",
"00010111",
"00011001"
]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.match` (with regexp `\d{8}/g` ) function which returns all `characters(8)`

```js
console.log("00010111001101000001011100011001".match(/\d{8}/g));
```

Comment: Important to point out is that the rest of the string will be discarded (ignored) if the length of the string is not a multiple of `8`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `substring`:

```
var s = "00010111001101000001011100011001"; 
var v = new Array();
for ( i = 0 ; i < s.length ; i+=8 ) {
    v[i/8] = s.substring(i,i+8);
}    
console.log(v);
```

Output:

```
["00010111", "00110100", "00010111", "00011001"]
```